# How to start a job or process when a job on another server finished?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, windows-services, etl

I want to send a mail or automatically start a job on my server as soon as a job on another server has finished successfully. I have access to the other server and can view the job status but I cannot change the job itself, which is running an SSIS package.

Basically, I want to start refreshing my database (via running an ETL through job) as soon as source has stopped refreshing itself. I would love to have suggestion beside this windows service implementation.

Comment: can you have the third party call a web service or is your trigger to do action the when files stop getting written to?

Comment: Two basic options.  `1.` Have the third party push a 'Finished' message.  `2.` Poll the third party yourself, and begin the ETL when you see that it has finished.  `Question?`  If the third party is allowed to call an SP on your server, or you're able to use the SQL Server Agent on your server, what in *particular* is proving to be a hurdle for you?

Comment: Microsoft SSIS, we write jobs in SQL Server 2008 which pick up these ETL packages and config files and run.

Comment: The problem here is I don't have access to source or in simple words can't make any change there. We have to detect it from our server and trigger the job. How thru windows service can we detect whether third party stopped its ETL (logging in thru ssms to there server and querying SYSSSISLOG via SSMS ??)

Comment: You still haven't explained how you know (or "detect") when the 3rd party ETL job is complete. Does it write a specific string to a text file? Does it update a database table with a flag or timestamp? Does it write a specific message to the Windows event log? Or something else? Without that information, you will not get a good answer. And if the 3rd party tool is a commercial product, you should mention the name: someone may have experience with it.

Comment: @Pondlife is right on the money here. We can't help you if you don't say what the third party tool *does* to indicate that it is finished. Is it SSIS? Informatica? DataStage?

Comment: @Pondlife This is what I want to know.. "How through windows service can I detect the successful job execution of source". For ETL we use SSIS technology. Source also uses the same. I m calling other server as source because we are using it to populate our tables. I just want to create a windows service that helps in detecting the success of source (other server) ETL (through which it refreshes itself)

Comment: @vaibhav I'm afraid you still haven't answered the question. Let me put it this way: if someone comes to you today and asks "has the external ETL job finished yet?", what do you look at manually in order to answer their question? Only then can someone tell you how to automate that check.

Comment: I m really very sorry if I have still not made myself clear. I would log into source server (via SSMS) check job history through job activity monitor whether it succeeded or not. I want to automatically start an ETL on my server as soon as the ETL of source gets finished. I also want to know is there any other way (as in checking log or something) we can detect the ETL success of source.

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of editing the question and title to make it more explicit. As I understand it from your description, you want to run a job (or start some other process) on server A when a job on server B has completed successfully. You cannot change the job definition on server B, but you can log on to it and view the job history.

If you can't change the job or anything else on server B, that means it cannot notify server A when the job is complete. Therefore, you need to query server B from server A, using a Windows service or possibly a simple script that runs every few minutes (or hours, or whatever is appropriate).

You can query the status of a job from .NET or PowerShell using the SMO [Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.job.aspx) class, or from TSQL using the [sp_help_job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186722.aspx) procedure. Which of these is a better solution depends on how you want to implement your polling mechanism.

Comment: Thanks a lot for updating my crappy written question ^.^. I'll implement one of the suggested ways and mark your answer correct as and when completed.